# how to load Jquery tab content everytimg it is clicked?

Tags: jquery-ui

I have 3 links made as tabs in my jsp page. Every link goes into a servlet and fetches the data. However when i try the same in IE-7, I don't see that tab content is getting loaded every-time i clicked the tab.

When i try the same page in Firefox i see that page is getting dynamically loaded every time i click the tab. Can someone please help me how to make it work on IE. All these links get data from 3 different servlets Thank you!

I am using jquery-1.7.2, jquery-ui-1.8.22 and using the Le_Frog theme.

My tab code:

```
$("#main").tabs({
cache: false,
spinner: "Processing"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the following code and it worked fine.

```
$("#main").tabs({
cache: false,
spinner: "Retrieving data...",
ajaxOptions: { async: false,cache:false }

});
```